# To select a row from a web table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexing, datatables

Here is the code that I used to select a row from this particular table. The following code has to select the row containing Position-"Engineer' and Age=34. Instead it is selecting the entire table. Can someone explain me why is this happening and what can be added to avoid it.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var dict={1:"Engineer",3:"34"};
  var a=Object.keys(dict);
    if ( (a+"").match(/^\d+$/) ) 
                {
                  var colidx = Object.keys(dict);
                  $('#example tbody tr').filter(function(idx, ele) {
                    var val = colidx.filter(function(colname, idx) {
                      var colvalue = dict[colname];
                      return ($(ele).find('td').eq(colidx[idx]).text() == colvalue)
                    });
                    return val.length == colidx.length }).css('background-color', 'red');
                }
             else 
                {
                  var coli = {};
                  $('#example thead tr th').filter(function(i, e) {
                    var keycol = e.textContent;
                    var keyval = Object.keys(dict).indexOf(keycol);
                    if (keyval != -1) {
                      coli[keycol] = i;
                    }
                  });
                  var colidx = Object.keys(coli);
                  $('#example tbody tr').filter(function(idx, ele) {
                    var val = colidx.filter(function(colname, idx) {
                      var colvalue = dict[colname];
                      var colindex = coli[colname];
                      return ($(ele).find('td').eq(colindex).text() == colvalue)
                    });
                    return val.length == colidx.length;
                  }).css('background-color', 'red');
      }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Kavya</td>
      <td>Engineer</td>
      <td>Mumbai</td>
      <td>34</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>1,20,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Archana</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Delhi</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>kranthi</td>
      <td>Technical Author</td>
      <td>Chennai</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>86,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Srija</td>
      <td>Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Pune</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2012/03/29</td>
      <td>433,060</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Priyanka</td>
      <td>Engineer</td>
      <td>Mysore</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>2008/11/28</td>
      <td>162,700</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Himanshu</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>Goa</td>
      <td>51</td>
      <td>2012/12/02</td>
      <td>372,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Vishwam</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Jharkand</td>
      <td>69</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Akhila</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>Hyderabad</td>
      <td>59</td>
      <td>2012/08/06</td>
      <td>137,500</td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashwini</td>
      <td>Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Bhuvaneshwar</td>
      <td>39</td>
      <td>2009/09/15</td>
      <td>205,500</td>
    </tr>
 
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: make a fiddle or create a snippet.. hard to tell what's going on... you say you want it to select a row and instead it's selecting the row? doesn't make any sense

Comment: @RachelGallen the following code is selecting the entire table.

Comment: Shouldn't 'match' be used on a string. You are using it on an array - a = Object.keys().

Comment: @Kenz check the solution i found for your example and let me know if suits your needs

Comment: @cralfaro i wanted a generalized solution for the entire table. it is not necessary that i would always locate the table using position and age. The code works perfect  but there is some problem with the if loop i guess.

Comment: @Kenz if you need a generic solution i would modify the function by selectRowByIndexValue(index, value) and send the cell index and the expected value, you can customize the function as you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this

UPDATE: Example using a dict with index-value and Name-value

```
$(function() {
  var dict = {0:"Srija", "Office": "Pune", 3: "22"};
  dict = buildIndexValueDictionary(dict);
  runSearchByDict(dict);
});

function buildIndexValueDictionary(dict){
  var header = $("table thead tr th")
  var result = {};
  for (var key in dict) {
    if(isNaN(key)){
      result[getIndexByColumnName(header, key)] = dict[key];
    }
    else{
      result[key] = dict[key];
    }
  }
  return result;
}

function getIndexByColumnName(header, key){
  for(var i = 0; i < header.length; i++){
    if($(header[i]).html() == key){
      return i;
    }
  }
}

function runSearchByDict(dict) {
      var arrayIndex = new Array();
      var arrayValues = new Array();
      for (var key in dict) {
        arrayIndex.push(key);
        arrayValues.push(dict[key]);
      }
      var matchedRows = selectRowByDict(arrayIndex, arrayValues);
      for (var i = 0; i < matchedRows.length; i++) {
        console.log($(matchedRows[i]).html());
      }
}

function selectRowByDict(arrayIndex, arrayValues){
  var result = new Array();
  var rows = $("table tbody tr");
  for(var j = 0; j < rows.length; j++){
    var cells = $(rows[j]).find("td");
    var validRow = true;
    for(var i = 0; i < arrayIndex.length && validRow; i++){
      if($(cells[arrayIndex[i]]).html() != arrayValues[i]){
        validRow = false;
      }
    }
    if(validRow){
      result.push($(rows[j]));
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: @cralfaro...the code must work the same way even with column names and value. Will it?!? Can you suggest how to get the data type of the keys from the dict. So that I'll modify my if loop.

Comment: @Kenz with the change i added now you could receive different dictionaries for your search and would return the list of rows which match the search.

Comment: @Kenz did you have time to verify if now its generic enough for your problem?#

Comment: this works fine with the indexes. But what if i send a dict={"Name":"Srija"}. I wanted the code to work for both indexes and column names too.

Comment: can you add comments to the code. I'm new to jquery and stuff,so that i can understand the code.

Comment: @gaetanoM Hey! Can you suggest me the 'IF-LOOP' condition for the following question.

Comment: @Kenz you need to add conditions to check if your dict its index-value or Name-value, then use the proper method. Its easy to modify with the current code

Comment: can you just help me out with that.

Comment: @Kenz which are all requeriments? those 2 types of dictionaries are the only 2 possibilities?

Comment: @Kenz I did the update, now you should be able to make the search with the 2 types of dictionaries

Comment: sorry for the late reply. But this doesn't work for these kinds of dictionaries ..dict={"name":"Srija",1:"Engineer"}.

Comment: @Kenz because you are mixing dictionaries, I did 2 options: Dictionary1=columnNames-values and Dictionary2:columnIndex-value, here you are mixing names and indexes

Comment: Can't I perform a search in that way. Coz anyways there's a for loop running on every key,right? It should work with both indexes and column names.

Comment: for example: dict1={column-name:value,column-index:value}

Comment: @Kenz Oks, then you only have to get my solution and mix it, identify when its an index or a column name, and will work, just mix the both solutions I did and build a new one

Comment: @Kenz keep trying, you just need to identify when its column-name and column-index and build a generic dictionary

Comment: you asked me to mix both the solutions. Which of them?

Comment: In my solution, I always make the search by column-index-value, so when its column-name-value i convert to index-value, you have to do the same now, but with the difference that some elements of the dictionary could be already in format index-value

Comment: can you help me out in getting the row from the table using both indexes and column names. When i'm giving both indexes and column names,for example: var dict={0:"Srija",Position:"Engineer"}, the index value is becoming undefined. Can you help me out with this.?

Comment: @Kenz, I modified the code to make a mix search now.

Comment: @cralfaro...I have marked it as answer :) I'm just curious to know ...can we find a row whose salary is greater than or lesser than?? Can we use operators such as greater than ,lesser than??

Comment: @Kenz Yes, we can, but you need to know which column/index have to use that comparison, now we check that the html value its the same as in the search, if you want to do that you have to convert from string to int and the use <= or >=

Comment: Okayy!! Thank you :)

Comment: @cralfaro...I'm using the code with necessary changes in it to test it with different table in visual studio ultimate 2012. But it isn't displaying the row in the console. There are no errors displayed.what can be the issue? Is it because of the html structure of another table??

Comment: @Kenz maybe its because the table structure, check that the dictionary you pass for the search its right, if the indexes or column names are not correct wont show anything